# Qt access variable from custom object from QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I have created my own `QGraphicsView` so I can use the `mousePressEvent` method. I then add the "new" widget to the MainWindow. Now I need to access a scene from that object, but I have trouble accessing it.

**privqgraphicsview.cpp**

```
#include "privqgraphicsview.h"
#include <QPointF>

MyQGraphicsView::MyQGraphicsView(QWidget *parent) :
    QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    this->setSceneRect(-320, -290, 660, 580);
    this->setScene(scene);
    this->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
}
```

**privqgraphicsview.h**

```
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QMouseEvent>

   class MyQGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
   {
       Q_OBJECT
   public:
       explicit MyQGraphicsView(QWidget *parent = 0);
       QGraphicsScene * scene;

   public slots:
       void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e);

   };
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "privqgraphicsview.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // gridLayout is defined in mainwindow.h
    gridLayout = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
    gridLayout->addWidget( new MyQGraphicsView() );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Now, I have the button in `MainWindow` on which click event I would like to connect points which are in `MyQGraphicsView`'s `scene` from `gridLayout`. I have tried something like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_connectPointsPB_clicked()
{
    QLayoutItem *myView = gridLayout->itemAt(0);
    // trying to draw a simple line, code below does not check anything, I am aware of it
    dynamic_cast<MyQGraphicsView *>(myView)->scene->addLine(10,10,50,50, QPen(Qt::red, 3));
}
```

And that does shutdown (crash) the app after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not cast `QLayoutItem`, but [`QLayoutItem::widget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#widget) to your `MyQGraphicsView`. If you checked the outcome of `dynamic_cast<MyQGraphicsView *>(myView)`, you would have noticed that it returns `NULL`. Note that it may be useful to use [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) instead of `dynamic_cast`, which does not require RTTI support.

**A cleaner solution** would be to store your `MyQGraphicsView` object as a member of `MainWindow`, so you do not need to cast anything.

Comment: Adding the `MyQGraphicsView` object as a member of `MainWindow` is the best way in my opinion, I haven't thought about that.